# Can this gyrator handle high current and/or high voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, inductor

Since I first got introduce to the Antoniou Inductor while in university, I've always been amazed at it. I've never built or used one, but I am thinking about using it to simulate an inductor for a future project.

Below is an image of the Anoniou Inductor.

[image]

My circuit will be pretty simple, as shown in the image below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJaeZ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My source will either be a fixed frequency +/- 30V square wave or a fixed frequency +/-1A square wave.

Question: Can I use this circuit with the given source voltage/current ?

I think it might be ok, if my opamp rails are high enough, and the passives between opamps are rated appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - in principle it should work. "In principle" means that ALL components must be rated appropriately (all resistors including R1, capacitor, power opamp?). In addition, please note that Antonious GIC circuit simulates a **grounded** inductor only (assuming that the opamps are powered with reference to the same ground).

Comment: My prof really drove the ground as well :)  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I've never built one either... (so this in an "in theory" type answer.)  The first thing you might want to do is to go through the circuit analysis.  This will give you an idea of the internal voltages and currents.  (Depending on how you choose the R's I think you can end up with gain inside the opamp circuits... which would mean the internal voltages might be bigger than the terminal voltages.)  So that is the first thing to look out for.

As far as using it with +/-30V or at +/- 1 amp at the input.  I think that will be much harder with your typical opamps.  Finding opamps that run on supplies that are higher than (say) +/- 15 to 18 volts is hard.  (or expensive) And getting a garden variety opamp to source/ sink 1 amp will be even more of a challenge.

I tend to think of these gyrator inductors as small signal inductors.  If you need real power I think you may need a "real" inductor.